# Search for strings in the binary file

Tags: linux, string, grep, binary

This command searches for strings in binary file:

```
strings somebinaryfile | grep text-to-find
```

If found, it returns a result without surrounding characters, but sometimes it necessary to show the surrounding strings around the found string(to understand the context): how to specify this?

Comment: Try `grep -C3` for 3 lines of context on either side.

Comment: @jamieguinan These are lines ... in a binary file that could be surprisingly a lot of data. On top of that, `strings` does not return those characters, so you cannot modify `grep` for this.